# Why is this WinForm in execution so different from its design?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a simple WinForm whose only function is to display a message passed to it.  The message is passed as a string and is displayed in a textbox. It is set to be a FixedToolWindow (and no matter how else I set it I get the same behavior in the end).

The form is called with:

```
PswCoordFailDisplay coord1 = new PswCoordFailDisplay(inputString);
coord1.Show();
```

Here are two screenshots: top is of the designer; bottom is how it is actually painted.

[image: Comparison Screenshots]

This is part of a fairly complicated application with about 10 other WinForms.  They all act like they're supposed to, except this one.

The changes from design are:

- the Form's dimensions change
- the textbox changes to occupy the entire width of the form (possibly in response to the size of the text that fills it -- although `ScrollBars` is set to `Both`)
- the Close button changes its text to "OK" and migrates to the bottom right
- the form's Title is gone
- the X-closer is different
- when I turn `ControlBox` to `False`, the X-closer appears regardless, and in the same form as in the bottom example

I pretty much take all the defaults that a WinForm provides when creating the WinForm, except for a couple of items that shouldn't make this kind of difference.

What on earth is happening?  I mean, it still *works* fine, but it's not what the design *calls* for!

Comment: Have you checked the code? The Load and/or Shown event may have handlers that rearrange things

Comment: you sure you aren't loading some other form?  add a messagebox on the Load event... do you see it?

Comment: What's the code behind the form? Step through executing the form in the debugger.

Comment: Can you add some code to see what you are doing?

Comment: @TMcKeown, you win the prize.  Execution went down a different path than I was expecting, and the text was being sent to a MessageBox, not the WinForm I designed.  I seem to have forgotten to modify the code to pass the text to the WinForm in one branch of a Switch statement, and thought it was going down a different branch.  It's apparently my day for looking stupider than usual.  Grrrr.

Comment: @GrantWinney, you win second place.  You and T McKeown nailed it.  Please beat me with a  wet noodle.

Comment: @GrantWinney, no, if anything it is time for a beer.  If I weren't a teetotaler, that's what I would do right now.  :-)

Comment: So, what idiot voted to close this question as not within the scope of StackOverflow?  Isn't SO intended to showcase programming mistakes, too, and not merely gnarly questions?

Comment: i just upvoted to cancel that down vote, totally legit question/problem.  happens to ALL of us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pay close attention to the pictured screenshots presented in the question, you will notice that the bottom one shows a **MessageBox**, not the intended WinForm.  As commenters T McKeown and Grant Winney pointed out, there is no way for the elements of the form to go that far off the rails unless the form was coded that way.  Since it wasn't coded that way, the expected form is NOT being called.  There is a very superficial resemblance, of course, which accounted for my confusion.

If I had showed the complete calling code, a sharp eye would have seen this quickly:

```
switch (opRes.OpResult)
{
    case OperationResult.Result.Succeeded :
        MessageBox.Show("Password coordination succeeded.");
        LoadUser();
        break;
    case OperationResult.Result.PartialSuccess :
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Password coordination partially succeeded: {0}{1}", Environment.NewLine, opRes.Notation));
        LoadUser();
        break;
    default :
        MessageBox.Show("Password coordination failed.");
        PswCoordFailDisplay coord1 = new PswCoordFailDisplay(opRes.Notation);
        coord1.Show();
        break;
}
```

As you can clearly see, with a "partial success" control would be passed to the second `case` in the `switch` statement, not the `default`.  The second `case` was supposed to be coded with the new WinForm, but I forgot to do it!  And so there you see the problem:

**READ YOUR DARNED CODE BEFORE POSTING YOUR PROBLEM ON STACKOVERFLOW!**

Less embarrassment that way.

**ETA:** Also, if I had posted the above code in my question, as @Rockster suggested, someone would have noticed it immediately, perhaps saving a step or two.